# how to move the cursor at the end of the richtext box in vb 2008

Tags: vb.net

i am adding an text while i press enter in the rich text box after that the cursor is in the top of the string how to make it at the end of the string

```
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + "enter"

        End If
```

can any one tell me how can i do that

Comment: please make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly, I think you need to do:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
```

If the text scrolls away, you might also need to do a:

```
RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
```